# Как можно изменять имя checkBox?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Есть CheckBox, с id Checkbox1 и текстом NameCheckBox 
(это все в .xml)

```
android:id="@+id/Checkbox1"
android:text="NameCheckBox"
```

Как изменить NameCheckBox, скажем на NameCheckBox3

```
CheckBox checkbox1 = findViewById(R.id.Checkbox1);
checkBox1.setText("NameCheckBox3");
```

если прописывать это в .java, то в процессе работы приложения текст не меняется

Comment: вы хотите изменить имя при выборе чекбокса?

Comment: Не хочу создавать большое количество окон, поэтому хочу по нажатию кнопки проверять их, а следом менять имя

Comment: не очень понятно если честно что именно вы пытаетесь реализовать, из вашего вопроса я так понял что вы хотите программно менять надпись в вашем чекбоксе, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы изменить название вашего checkBox программно, вам нужно использовать слушатель изменения состояния этого виджета. После объявления вашего `checkBox`:

```
CheckBox checkbox1 = findViewById(R.id.Checkbox1);
```

вам нужно добавить слушатель таким образом:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           if(isChecked)
            {
              checkbox1.setText("ваш текст");
            }

       }
   }
);
```

то есть если ваш чекбокс выбран то вы указываете в нем другой текст, который вам нужен. Надеюсь это решит вашу проблему, если возникнут сложности - не стесняйтесь и пишите, постараемся помочь. Удачи :)